# Google app engine mobile application getting error

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am creating mobile application in android using google app engine endpoits. I have created endpoints and add all jars and packages in my mobile application by creating cleient endpoint library.

this is my code to create builder and call API

```
Employeeendpoint.Builder builder = new Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
            null);
    builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);
    Employeeendpoint endpoint = builder.build();
    try {

        Employee s = endpoint.getEmployee("2").execute();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but this will give me below error,

```
Could not find class 'com.appspot.fuogydemo.employeeendpoint.Employeeendpoint$Builder', referenced from method com.example.sample.MainActivity.onCreate
```

Where as this class is present in my application

```
public Builder(com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport transport, com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory jsonFactory,
    com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {
  super(
      transport,
      jsonFactory,
      DEFAULT_ROOT_URL,
      DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH,
      httpRequestInitializer,
      false);
}

/** Builds a new instance of {@link Employeeendpoint}. */
@Override
public Employeeendpoint build() {
  return new Employeeendpoint(this);
}

@Override
public Builder setRootUrl(String rootUrl) {
  return (Builder) super.setRootUrl(rootUrl);
}

@Override
public Builder setServicePath(String servicePath) {
  return (Builder) super.setServicePath(servicePath);
}

@Override
public Builder setHttpRequestInitializer(com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {
  return (Builder) super.setHttpRequestInitializer(httpRequestInitializer);
}

@Override
public Builder setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
  return (Builder) super.setApplicationName(applicationName);
}

@Override
public Builder setSuppressPatternChecks(boolean suppressPatternChecks) {
  return (Builder) super.setSuppressPatternChecks(suppressPatternChecks);
}

@Override
public Builder setSuppressRequiredParameterChecks(boolean suppressRequiredParameterChecks) {
  return (Builder) super.setSuppressRequiredParameterChecks(suppressRequiredParameterChecks);
}

@Override
public Builder setSuppressAllChecks(boolean suppressAllChecks) {
  return (Builder) super.setSuppressAllChecks(suppressAllChecks);
}

/**
 * Set the {@link EmployeeendpointRequestInitializer}.
 *
 * @since 1.12
 */
public Builder setEmployeeendpointRequestInitializer(
    EmployeeendpointRequestInitializer employeeendpointRequestInitializer) {
  return (Builder) super.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(employeeendpointRequestInitializer);
}

@Override
public Builder setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer googleClientRequestInitializer) {
  return (Builder) super.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(googleClientRequestInitializer);
}
```

}

So please any one help me out what is problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that the package name is the same you have in the rest of your code?

Comment: @Mario Yes package name is same in rest code.

Comment: Are you sure? it's a cryptic name and the error it's that it can't find that class.